# network connectivity issues with Vultr and Google Cloud services

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

All,

I have been trying to track down reasons for a while now, that my connection to google cloud translations has intermittent network issues.  First I used googleTranslate v2, and was getting timeout errors on the detect interface.  Then I switched to v3, and it too, seems like I get network timeout errors.

I develop on windows laptop, and the code works fine, no timeouts.  (at my home network).

```
const testTranslate = await googleTranslate(messageText, cEnglish).catch(err => { console.error(err); return (languages); });
```

When I move the code to Vultr VM, and run same, it gets timeouts, intermittently:

```
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/root/bots/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/root/node-Modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/root/node-Modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:334:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/root/node-Modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:297:181)
at /root/bots/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:130:78
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
code: 14,
details: 'No connection established',
metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} }
}
```

Looking for debug ideas as to why my VM (yes different OS and lib versions exist too) might be failing...

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

for anyone that might come across this....I never was able to resolve this.  Part of my end solution was to implement a retry mechanism, to handle network connection disruptions.  These are a fact of life, and adding this into the code just handles robustness and is needed.

However, this didn't solve my problem.  There is still some sort of continual network connection issue with my vultr instance and to google.  I wasn't interested in debugging this because it was too difficlut to reporduce and I couldn't just drop my day job to debug it.  I found a google cloud instance that was equivalent to vultr ( which I chose vultr because it was cheapest compute node I could find)....and gcp is now just as cheap.

I moved there, and the network issues disappeared....code didn't change.